# Переадрессация и фильтры в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация, filter

Возникла проблема с выполнением блокировки пользователей на сайте. А именно, нет понимания как сделать автоматическое открытие страницы с информацией о блокировке на ресурсе. Т.е если пользователь был забанен, то вместо личного кабинета, сообщений, домашней страницы и т.д ему при открытии сайта будет открываться именно view с блокировкой. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать с такой проблемой?

Comment: Добавить в таблицу столбец `Blocked` . При обращении в контроллер проверять, если `true` то выводится страница с информацией о блокировке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class LockoutFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        var pUser = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        var user = //Логика для поиска пользователя;
        if (user.LockoutDate > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        var user = //Логика для поиска пользователя;
        if (user.LockoutDate > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary {
                {"controller", "Home"},
                {"action",  "LockoutAction"}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Примерно так будет выглядеть, наверное...
Останется только добавить это к глобальным фильтрам, ну или к нужным маршрутам. Минус в том, что это редирект. Если необходимо оставлять пользователя на этой же странице нужно что-то вроде:

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult{ViewName=..., Model=...};
```